# Pushing to GitHub stuck on “Writing Objects: 100%”

Tags: git, github, git-push, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit on Windows to push to GitHub. The version of TortoiseGit and msysgit are all up to date. However someone said the recent version of msysgit is buggy so I downgraded it to v1.7.3.

```
git.exe push --thin --progress  "origin" master:master
Counting objects: 167, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (152/152), done.
Writing objects: 100% (166/166), 64.45 MiB | 2.33 MiB/s, done.
Total 166 (delta 39), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

It hangs up here. After I deleted some large files (no larger than 100MB) the problem disappeared.

Comment: After I deleted some large files (Not larger than 100MB) the problems disappeared. I wondered if it's a problem of git or github.

Answer (score 2):

The "[What is my disk quota?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota)" GitHub help page does mention:

> we place a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size

It is possible it manifests by an incomplete push, even though you should see a more explicit warning:

> GitHub warns you when you push a file larger than 50 MB. We'll reject pushes containing files larger than 100 MB

A tool like [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) can help you get rid of large files in your local repo history.